# Exporting XSD and WSDL from WCF Service (SVCUTIL)

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a Wcf Service with a simple method. I need to generate the WSDL and XSD file, to handover to third-party that needs to use the webservice.

The solution is done in Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5. From the BIN folder, I run the SVCUTIL /t:metadata {name of dll file}. Shortly after I now have both a WSDL and a XSD file. The WSDL file contains:

```
[SAPI XML] tempuri.org.wsdl(2): unknown tag <wsdl:definitions>.
[SAPI XML] Compulation Failed!
[W3C XML tempuri.org.wsdl(2) : The name of the root element in the grammar must be     "grammar", not "definition".
[W3C XML] Compilation Failed!
```

It's almost the same output for the XSD file.

Any ideas?

ThanTheks
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Loaded the project in VS2012 (on another PC), build and ran the SVCUTIL.EXE - this time no problems. Maybe related to the SVCUTIL installed on my VS2013 installed PC.